# Excel, index find horizontal value

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

I have a table with some planning. We have our volunteers in colums and dates in rows. We use an "x" to mark when they have a duty:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9IFk.png)

Now I want to make a resume where I specify a date, and see which name comes up who has duty. So I would like to search vertical for comparison of the date and  find the "b" or "x", but then return the name that would be in the column of row 8.

So when I select for example "sunday 16-12-18" as a date, I would like to have name "Riekelt Keuter" as result (out of G to J). (D to F is one division, G to J is another division). D to F would be another query.

Thanks in advance,

Greetings Riekelt Keuter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is an attempt, using one index match to match the person to each day and the other index match to find the day and return the person...
See:
[image]

Column I is the "extra" helper column matching person to list of days...

Comment: Many thanks for this solution. Now I have another question. What if the colums can contain or "x" or "b". Can Match("x"... also be formulated to look for "b" also?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a simplere way but I can't think of it now:

`=OFFSET($A$1,,MATCH("X",OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(G1,$A$2:$A$7,0),1,1,3)))`

[image]

Comment: Hi Michal, many thanks for your quick answer. I had to adjust the formula a little for my (dutch) language and a bit other offset.

Comment: Hi @Michal, many thanks for your quick answer. I had to adjust the formula a little for my (dutch) language and a bit other offset. `code` =VERSCHUIVING(Rooster!$A$8;;VERGELIJKEN("X";VERSCHUIVING(Rooster!$A$8;VERGELIJKEN($B$3;Rooster!$A$9:Rooster!$A$177;0);1;1;5))) (Rooster! is my main tab, verschuiving=offset, vergelijken=match and , is ; for me). Now I had to change the 3 value to 5 because I start in col D (to F). My next query would be only on col G to J but I can't get it to work by changing the value 3... Thanks.